# Issue converting custom type array into data | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I would like to convert an array of the following custom struct into data for data for easier saving in CoreData as Binary Data. How can the following be converted into data to then be ready to decode back:

**Custom Struct**

```
struct Place: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var coordinate: Coordinate
    
    struct Coordinate: Codable {
        let latitude: Double
        let longitude: Double

        func locationCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude,
                                          longitude: self.longitude)
        }
    }
}
```

**Adding to Custom Struct**

```
var mapAddresses = [Place]()

Task {
  mapAddresses.append(Place(coordinate: try await getCoordinate(from: 
  post.location)))
}
```

The issue I am having is converting the array mapAddresses with the custom structure into Binary Data, that can then be decoded back into the custom array.

Comment: You wrote “Issue converting…” but never explained what the issue is?

Comment: @Terra, an `Array` of a type that conforms to `Codable` should itself conform to `Codable`, so it's not clear what you are asking.  Please provide an example of the code you'd like to write (and probably tried) to encode and decode the array along with the error(s) that you're getting.  We can then help you figure out what's going on with that.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, the issue is that I do not understand how to convert mapAddresses into Binary Data.

Comment: @Terra, well to encode/decode from a standard encoder/decoder you do it just like any `Codable` type, just pass `[Place].self` instead of the `Place.self`.  The most popular encoder and decoder are `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder`, but technically these don't encode to *binary* except in as much as text is binary.  If you want a more compact binary encoding, you can use `PropertyListEncoder/Decoder` setting its `outputFormat` property to `.binary`

Comment: Or you *could* write you're own custom encoder to encode to any binary format you like, which could be a lot more efficient than either JSON or Plist.

Comment: BTW to use `PropertyListEncoder` for *binary* format, you can't do it with the usual one-line instantiation and encode like you would for `JSONEncoder`, because you have to set the `outputFormat` property as a separate step, so it's `let encoder = PropertyListEncoder(); encoder.outputFormat = .binary; guard let data = try? encoder.encode(mapAddresses) else {...}`

Comment: @ChipJarred I appreciate your help, can you please show a full version of PropertyListEncoder example? Can I then decode the data as normal?

Comment: @Terra, I posted an answer that I think will answer your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, your phrasing indicates that you want a *binary* encoding. I'll get to that, but first let's just encode/decode JSON.

Given

```swift
struct Place: Codable {...}

let mapAddresses: [Place] = ...
```

The following code encodes `mapAddresses`, then immediately decodes the resulting `Data`:

```swift
guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(mapAddresses) else {
    fatalError("Failed to encode")
}

guard let decodedMapAddresses = 
    try? JSONDecoder().decode([Place].self, from: data) 
else { fatalError("Failed to decode") }
```

Whether `data` is *binary* is a matter of interpretation.  `data` will just contain the text of the JSON representing `mapAddresses`.  Technically text is binary, but then again so is anything else in a computer.  What we normally mean is non-text, that is some more compact or more directly machine-friendly encoding that is not so human-friendly.  `JSONEncoder` doesn't provide such a facility, but `PropertyListEncoder` does, via it's `outputFormat` property.   To use it:

```swift
let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
encoder.outputFormat = .binary

guard let data = encoder.encode(mapAddresses) else {
    fatalError("Failed to encode")
}

guard let decodedMapAddresses = 
    try? PropertyListDecoder().decode([Place].self, from: data)
else { fatalError("Failed to decode") }
```

Note there is no need specify that it's binary in the decoder, because `PropertyListDecoder` knows how to detect that.

Comment: Got it, thank you. How would go about finding a solution to solving an issue like this? What is your thought process behind finding a solution like PropertyListEncoder? Are you just well versed in the documentation or based on lots of trial and error. I've been researching how to do this for a bit and couldn't find a solution. Any tips?

Comment: It helps having "been around the block a few times."  I've been writing Macintosh software software going back to classic Macintosh, so I've seen a lot of evolution.  When Apple introduced OS X (rebranded macOS), there was no JSON.  They used property lists everywhere and still do in many places, and that goes back to when it was NeXT, which was in a time when memory was a lot more limited, so binary encoding was more prevalent.   I still remember that.

Comment: Since iOS is newer, you'll encounter a lot fewer such things, though much of it can be applied in iOS, tvOS, and watchOS too.   macOS is a lot older, so try doing writing code for macOS, and you'll slowly learn a lot, like why UIKit is the way it is - It's basically AppKit modified for a small format touch screen environment with no mouse, which in turn inherited from NeXTStep.  And you'll see a lot more older things like encodings that are still actively used on macOS, but not so much on newer OSes in the Apple ecosystem.

Comment: The main reason I wanted to see the data in a "Binary" data format was to store it easier in Core Data. This way I can easily store it as Binary data in a single field and decode it when I need to.

Comment: Although encoding/decoding to/from binary plists is faster than JSON, if you'd prefer the readability of JSON, even using CoreData, `JSONEncoder` still returns `Data`.  It's just that it's byte-content is UTF-8 encoded text.  You should be able to store/retrieve that with CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said in the comments, you don't have a fully-formed question yet. But first, you don't need `Coordinate`. Just make `CLLocationCoordinate2D` Codable, like Apple should have.

```swift
import struct CoreLocation.CLLocationCoordinate2D

public extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
  enum CodingKey: Swift.CodingKey {
    case latitude
    case longitude
  }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Decodable {
  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    try self.init(
      Self.init, (CodingKey.latitude, .longitude),
      decoder: decoder
    )
  }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Encodable {
  public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKey.self)
    try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
    try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Decodable {
  /// Initialize using 2 keyed, decoded arguments.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - init: An initializer (or  factory function) whose arguments are the decoded values.
  ///   - keys: `CodingKey` instances, matching the arguments.
  init<
    Parameter0: Decodable, Parameter1: Decodable, Key: CodingKey
  >(
    _ init: (Parameter0, Parameter1) -> Self,
    _ keys: (Key, Key),
    decoder: Decoder
  ) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
    self = try `init`(
      container.decode(forKey: keys.0),
      container.decode(forKey: keys.1)
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol {
  /// Decode, relying on the return type, to avoid having to explicitly use a metatype argument.
  func decode<Decodable: Swift.Decodable>(forKey key: Key) throws -> Decodable {
    try decode(Decodable.self, forKey: key)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, to clarify my question, I do not quite understand how to convert the custom array mapAddresses into Binary data.